# remove sprite if reaches out of camera height

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

i am working on a game project similar to fruit ninja 
now where i stuck is when fruit bounce to screen and goes downword i want to deatach tht fruit from screen when reaches to camerascreen downword

```
       if (mHardware1[active].collidesWith(CamerScene)) {
        this.mHardware1[active].detachchild();

    }
```

its not working my camera height is 444 i want to remove mHardware1[active] if reaches >camera height

```
      if (mHardware1[active].getY>=444) {
        this.mHardware1[active].detachchild();

    }
```

is also not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.mHardware1[active].detachSelf();
```

or

```
scene.detachchild(this.mHardware1[active]);
```

Comment: ya @Alexey thnx for you help but i am not asking for this that how to remove a sprite but i want to knw about the condition that how can i apply the condition tht when sprite reaches to end of camera height it get destoryd

Comment: oh sry. if you use GLES2-AnchorCenter your condition must be `mHardware1[active].getY() < 0`